# Show a tooltip on React flow edge label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, react-flow

I want to show a Tooltip whenever I hover over an Edge Label in React flow.
[image]

What I want is whenever we hover over any of the labels a tooltip comes up. Can anyone tell how I can achieve this?

Comment: hi, did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: Looking to do the same thing

Comment: I was looking for the same thing and came across the react flow documentation. Using `pointerEvents: 'all'` will allow a pointer to make the element interactive. https://reactflow.dev/docs/examples/edges/custom-edge/